# How to edit BIOS information for a virtual machine in VMWare?

Tags: virtual-machine, bios, vmware

The manufacturer, as set in the BIOS of my VM, is "VMWare". I want to change that to other string. How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Virtual Machine and OEM license for Windows](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/88477-virtual-machine-and-oem-license-for-windows/page__p__597316#entry597316) for the only way I could find of modifying the manufacturer.

According to it, if your computer is known to VMware, then by adding to the virtual machine's configuration file (vmx) the option:

```
SMBIOS.reflectHost = TRUE
```

then the Manufacturer and Product Name strings in the virtual machine become the same as the Manufacturer and Product Name of the host system. This requires the destination host to have the same hardware as the guest.

This is as far as I will go, as modding the VMware BIOS is somewhat on the edge of legality. If you wish to go this way, [this](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/11152-VMware-Workstation-%28Multi-Brand%29-Bios-Installer) is a start.